# How do I enable CORS on GUnicorn?

Tags: python, cors, web-deployment, gunicorn

I built an API with Swagger, Python, Falsy and I want to display it on a website. I can display the API on a localhost server but when I try on anything other then localhost. I get a response that CORS is not enabled. How do I enable CORS on my system using Gunicorn to deploy the server?

Comment: how to resolved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Gunicorn doesn't contain this functionality. However, if you are using Gunicorn to serve a Flask app, you can enable CORS using a python module: [flask-cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can be installed like:

```
python3 -m pip install flask-cors
```

then in your flask application:

```
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

If you aren't using Flask for your framework, you can consult this resource for more information: https://enable-cors.org/server.html